# 2D vector issue in c++

Tags: c++, vector, minesweeper, 2d-vector

this is part of a larger basic minesweeper program. In the main cpp file of this program, I am loading all of the values of a matrix into a 2d vector of type int. Basically this matrix is filled with 1's and 0's which will be used to indicate whether a mine is there or not. I have confirmed through cout's that both the original vector and the referenced vector are outputting the matrices I loaded into them.

I have create a struct cell which contains 3 various conditions that it can be in. I have created a 2d vector of type cell which basically creates 3 vectors simultaneously. I am having trouble loading the referenced vector's values of 1's and 0's into minesweeperBoard[i][j].isMine.

Here is my code:

```
include <iostream>
include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct cell{
int state;                      //( 0 hidden, 1 revealed, 2 marked)
int value;                      //(-1 mine, 0 no surrounding, # > 0 number of surrounding mines)
bool isMine;
};


void minesweeper(int row, int col, int numOfMines, vector<vector<int> >&mineField) {

rowNum = row;
colNum = col;
minesNum = numOfMines;

    int temp;

for (int i = 0; i < rowNum; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < colNum; j++) {
        temp=mineField[i][j];
            if (temp ==0) {
                minesweeperBoard[i][j].isMine = false;  //will set minesweeper to false if the condition is met
            }
            else {
                minesweeperBoard[i][j].isMine = true;   //wil set minesweeper to true if the condition is met
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The program is compiling but throws an error once it reaches this point. What am I doing wrong is this not how I should transfer the states to the isMine vector.

In my main, I open the file and read several pieces of data, the rows, columns, and amount of mines. Then the file contains a giant matrix of said rows and columns which I feed into the vector. I then pass the vector. Keep in mind that the original void function is actually a class member hence the declaration in the main resembling that. I hope I'm not confusing you guys.

```
 file >> rows >> columns >> mines;

//declare mine field vector of int
vector<vector<int> > mineField(rows, vector<int> (columns));


//Set's the elements of the .txt matrix to an array
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
        file_difficulty >> mineField[i][j];
    }
}

minesweeper:minesweeper play(columns, rows, mines, mineField);
```

Just realized that minesweeperBoard is not declared at all in either the constructor or the other function.

Comment: what is `minesweeperBoard` and where do you declare/initialize it?

Comment: there are more errors, that wont make this code compile. Please provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: sorry, the code above is just a snippet of the project. minesweeper is actually a class and this is one of the functions. minesweeperBoard is a private member and is declared as                                      vector<vector<cell> > minesweeperBoard;

Comment: I don't want to make it super complicated which is why I left out a lot of code. The main basically asks a user which minesweeper file they would like to use, loads the file, reads from it the actual board which it stores into a vector. I have created an object of type minesweeper and i send the rows, columns, mines, and the vector of mine locations to the code you see above.

Comment: it is supercomplicated when we cannot reproduce the error. You dont have to post the original code, but you should post code that allows others to reproduce the error.

Comment: @sharyar - tobi is being nice when asking if `minesweeperBoard` and `mineField` are initialized to the correct sizes. Otherwise all the `[i][j]` indexing might be out-of-bounds. That's about what can go wrong in the code you have shown. So perhaps the real error is somewhere else?

Comment: @BoPersson  Thats what I think is incorrect. I will update the question momentarily.

Comment: Why do you require the user to give you the size as parameters; I guess that mineField has not the same size given by the user (test it!), but in principal you should give more information as said by the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me guess: you have inverted the order of `rows` and `columns` in this declaration

```
minesweeper:minesweeper play(columns, rows, mines, mineField);
```

and should be

```
minesweeper:minesweeper play(rows, columns, mines, mineField);
```